# Apache/mod_perl randomly fails

Tags: apache, mod-perl

We are running a web-based application on Ubuntu/Apache/mod_perl and with increased use we are starting to randomly experience problems with our programs.

The server is running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and Apache/2.4.18. But this happens on different servers with different Ubuntu and Apache versions.

It can run fine for hours and then fail repeatedly for about a minute. I can understand if it was our code which fails and if it was doing so in a consequent way but it feels like the problem is something else than the error logs indicates.

Below is some lines taken from the /var/log/apache/error.log
The first (and last) couple of lines show errors in our code/modules (which ran perfectly just before this) but then it starts to fail in ModPerl::Registry, Hash::Merge, etc. I'm totally out of debugging ideas.
I have noted that the same kind of error comes from the same Apache pid (different thread ids) if that is a clue in any way...

```
[Mon Oct 14 15:24:43.513420 2019] [:error] [pid 97911:tid 140590008215296] Attempt to reload WebGUI.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 13.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 13.\n
[Mon Oct 14 15:24:44.722253 2019] [:error] [pid 97911:tid 140589941073664] Attempt to reload WebGUI.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 13.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 13.\n
[Mon Oct 14 15:24:45.586512 2019] [:error] [pid 97911:tid 140589924288256] Attempt to reload WebGUI.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 13.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 13.\n
[Mon Oct 14 15:27:05.083671 2019] [perl:error] [pid 15164:tid 140590016608000] [client 66.109.33.18:57443] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Global symbol "$VERSION" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $VERSION"?) at /usr/share/perl/5.22/base.pm line 5.\nGlobal symbol "$VERSION" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $VERSION"?) at /usr/share/perl/5.22/base.pm line 6.\nGlobal symbol "$VERSION" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $VERSION"?) at /usr/share/perl/5.22/base.pm line 6.\nCompilation failed in require at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/ModPerl/Registry.pm line 27.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/ModPerl/Registry.pm line 27.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 15:27:05.129761 2019] [perl:error] [pid 15164:tid 140590008215296] [client 66.109.33.18:39384] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 3) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 15:27:05.852243 2019] [perl:error] [pid 15164:tid 140589991429888] [client 75.112.148.15:38062] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 15:27:06.893502 2019] [perl:error] [pid 15164:tid 140589983037184] [client 75.112.148.15:38064] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 5) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 15:45:22.457316 2019] [perl:error] [pid 12288:tid 140590033393408] [client 66.109.33.18:4390] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Can't locate object method "install_aliases" via package "ModPerl::Registry" at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/ModPerl/Registry.pm line 70.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 15:45:26.659826 2019] [perl:error] [pid 12288:tid 140589915895552] [client 75.112.148.15:40162] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 16:08:56.112937 2019] [perl:error] [pid 22685:tid 140590157600512] [client 172.16.2.36:37144] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Global symbol "$VERSION" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $VERSION"?) at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/File/Spec.pm line 6.\nGlobal symbol "$VERSION" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $VERSION"?) at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/File/Spec.pm line 7.\nGlobal symbol "@ISA" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @ISA"?) at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/File/Spec.pm line 22.\nCompilation failed in require at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/File/Spec/Functions.pm line 3.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/File/Spec/Functions.pm line 3.\nCompilation failed in require at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/ModPerl/RegistryCooker.pm line 46.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/ModPerl/RegistryCooker.pm line 46.\nCompilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.22/base.pm line 97.\n\t...propagated at /usr/share/perl/5.22/base.pm line 106.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/ModPerl/Registry.pm line 27.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 16:08:56.372992 2019] [perl:error] [pid 22685:tid 140590149207808] [client 97.68.152.67:55067] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 16:09:02.533403 2019] [perl:error] [pid 22685:tid 140590050178816] [client 172.16.2.36:37152] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 5) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 16:09:05.121083 2019] [perl:error] [pid 22685:tid 140589957859072] [client 66.109.33.18:52036] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 6) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 16:09:05.222048 2019] [perl:error] [pid 22685:tid 140589949466368] [client 66.109.33.18:46229] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 7) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 16:09:05.245198 2019] [perl:error] [pid 22685:tid 140589941073664] [client 75.112.148.15:42640] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 8) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 16:09:05.284797 2019] [perl:error] [pid 22685:tid 140589966251776] [client 75.112.148.15:42642] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 9) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 16:09:05.323840 2019] [perl:error] [pid 22685:tid 140589932680960] [client 75.112.148.15:42644] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 10) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 16:09:05.455646 2019] [perl:error] [pid 22685:tid 140589915895552] [client 172.16.2.27:33724] failed to resolve handler `ModPerl::Registry': Attempt to reload ModPerl/Registry.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 11) line 2.\n
[Mon Oct 14 17:44:20.506512 2019] [:error] [pid 93924:tid 140590149207808] syntax error at /usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm line 111, near "croak "Behavior '$beh' does not exist""\nGlobal symbol "$beh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $beh"?) at /usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm line 111.\nGlobal symbol "$beh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $beh"?) at /usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm line 114.\nGlobal symbol "$beh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $beh"?) at /usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm line 115.\nGlobal symbol "$pkg" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $pkg"?) at /usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm line 116.\nsyntax error at /usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm line 117, near "}"\nsyntax error at /usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm line 123, near "carp 'Behavior must be one of : '"\nsyntax error at /usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm line 123, near "} }"\nsyntax error at /usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm line 125, near "}"\nsyntax error at /usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm line 130, near "}"\n/usr/share/perl5/Hash/Merge.pm has too many errors.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/vps/lib/Time.pm line 5.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/vps/lib/Time.pm line 5.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/vps/lib/ProcessDefinition.pm line 19.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/vps/lib/ProcessDefinition.pm line 19.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/vps/lib/Session.pm line 9.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/vps/lib/Session.pm line 9.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 11.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 11.\n
[Mon Oct 14 17:44:20.547596 2019] [:error] [pid 93924:tid 140590140815104] Attempt to reload Session.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 11.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 11.\n
[Mon Oct 14 17:44:20.587327 2019] [:error] [pid 93924:tid 140590132422400] Attempt to reload Session.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 11.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 11.\n
[Mon Oct 14 17:44:20.641751 2019] [:error] [pid 93924:tid 140590041786112] Attempt to reload Session.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 11.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/vps/cgi/ANPR/ndi_bridge line 11.\n
```